# Filter a table for two conditions and then duplicate

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am trying to extract data from a table;

```
SELECT *  
FROM table 
WHERE column1 = value AND column2 = value;
```

After doing that I want to filter results for duplicates. I am using access 2007-2013. I am looking for SQL syntax please.

Answer (score 1):

Is **`DISTINCT`** what you're looking for ?

```
SELECT DISTINCT * 
FROM table 
WHERE column1 = value AND column2 = value;
```

[ALL, DISTINCT, DISTINCTROW, TOP Predicates (Microsoft Access SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb177882(v=office.12).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Use [`distinct`](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp):

```
SELECT distinct *  
FROM table 
WHERE column1 = value AND column2 = value;
```